# Local variable referenced before assignment in for loop

Tags: python, syntax-error

We have to read a trajectory xyz file (py3dmol), calculate the bond lengths between the C and O atoms for all "phases" and add those bond lengths to a list.
When I try to execute it with a given file, it gives me the error "local variable 'c_line' referenced before assignment". I think I understand what the problem is - that I have to tell the loop to continue with the variables it assigned in the statements, but how do I solve it? I have tried putting the coordinates-assignments (`c_x = etc`) in the if statements, but then either the same error is triggered in the `co_vector` line for `o_x` or it the function doesnt return anything.

Or am I doing it completely wrong? I have tried every variation I can think off but I'm getting the feeling I might have a mental blockade.

EDIT: i understand what the problem is. The if-statement only allows for either `c_line` or `o_line` to be defined one at a time, while I need both of them to be defined for each loop to execute the calculations. But I don't know how to find those specific lines in the file without searching for them via the if-statement. (I hope that makes sense) Any ideas how I can circumvent that problem? In the assignment it says the we are supposed to use an if-statement in some way.

```
def co_bond(file):
    
    file = open(file,'r') ## read file
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    
    bond_list = []
    c_x = 0
    c_y = 0
    c_z = 0
    
    o_x = 0
    o_y = 0
    o_z = 0
    
    for line in lines: # loop through entire file
        if line.startswith("c"):  # find c-atom lines
            c_line = line.split()[1:] # have only coordinates (first item is atom name)                  
        elif line.startswith("o"): # find o-atom lines
            o_line = line.split()[1:]         
        
        c_x = float(c_line[0]) # create c-atom coordinates
        c_y = float(c_line[1])
        c_z = float(c_line[2]) 
        
        o_x = float(o_line[0]) # create o-atom coordinates
        o_y = float(o_line[1])
        o_z = float(o_line[2])
        
        co_vector = [o_x - c_x, o_y - c_y, o_z - c_z] # create vector between c and o
        co_length = sqrt(co_vector[0]**2 + co_vector[1]**2 + co_vector[2]**2) # calculate bondlength
        
        bond_list_filled = bond_list.append(co_length)
        
    return bond_list_filled
```

Comment: What do you want `c_line` to be if `line.startswith("c")` is False? `c_line` only exists if that's True.

Comment: These variables are defined _only_ in the `if` statement. However, only _one_ path of an `if` statement can be taken at a time, so one of these variables is _guaranteed_ to be undefined.

Comment: This code doesn't make a ton of sense though. Only `c_line` **or** `o_line` can exist, but you require both to exist when you do `[o_x - c_x, o_y - c_y, o_z - c_z]`.

Comment: Ok I see the problem with it only being able to take one route at a time. Any ideas how I can solve it tho? I need both o_line and c_line to be defined at the same time, but I don't know how to define them without the if statement.

Comment: It isn't super clear what you're trying to do. Maybe store the `c_*` and `o_*` variables in their own lists in the first loop, then go over those lists in a separate loop afterward and calculate `co_vector` in the second loop using data from the lists?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if line.startswith("c"):  # find c-atom lines
        c_line = line.split()[1:] # have only coordinates (first item is atom name) 
        c_x = float(c_line[0]) # create c-atom coordinates
        c_y = float(c_line[1])
        c_z = float(c_line[2]) 

             
    elif line.startswith("o"): # find o-atom lines
        o_line = line.split()[1:]         
        o_x = float(o_line[0]) # create o-atom coordinates
        o_y = float(o_line[1])
        o_z = float(o_line[2])
```

Problem is that when one of the lines is an o-atom, you do not define c_line but you use it when doing c_line[0]. So you reference the variable c_line before you assigned a value to it.

Comment: This solves the immediate problem, but they require both sets of the `c_*` and `o_*` variables to exist at the same time.

Comment: You can give a default value at beginning of the loop for every c_* and o_*. Or leave the c_* and o_* outside the if_else and give a default c_line/o_line at beginning of the loop.

Comment: yea i've tried that but then it returns nothing (as in the return is none)

Comment: @houseanobis That's because `append` returns `None`, and you're doing `bond_list_filled = bond_list.append(co_length)`, then returning `bond_fill_list`.

Comment: Well spotted, @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am very stupid. After rewriting the code from scratch several times, I realized that one of the versions I had tried with the original answer was correct. However, the key line that screwed me over was:
`bond_list_filled = bond_list.append(co_length)`. After changing it to just `bond_list.append(co_length)`, it worked perfectly fine.

Here are two version that work for anybody that might be curious:

(1) a slighty changed version from what i originally posted

```
def co_bond(file):
    
    file = open(file,'r') # read file
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    
    bond_list = []
    c_x = 0
    c_y = 0
    c_z = 0
    
    o_x = 0
    o_y = 0
    o_z = 0
    
    for line in lines: # loop through entire file
        if line.startswith("c"):  # find c lines
            c_line = line.split()[1:]         
    
            c_x = float(c_line[0]) # create c coordinates
            c_y = float(c_line[1])
            c_z = float(c_line[2]) 
    
    for line in lines: 
        if line.startswith("o"): # find o lines
            o_line = line.split()[1:] 
            
            o_x = float(o_line[0]) # create o coordinates
            o_y = float(o_line[1])
            o_z = float(o_line[2])
        
        co_vector = [o_x - c_x, o_y - c_y, o_z - c_z] # create vector
        co_length = sqrt(co_vector[0]**2 + co_vector[1]**2 + co_vector[2]**2) # calculate length
        
        bond_list.append(co_length)
        
    return bond_list
```

(2) the thing I rewrote:

```
def co_bond(file):
    
    file = open(file,'r') # read file
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    
    bond_list = []
    c_line_list = []
    o_line_list = []
    
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("c"):  # find c lines
            c_line = line.split()[1:]
            c_line_list.append(c_line)
            
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("o"):  # find c lines
            o_line = line.split()[1:]
            o_line_list.append(o_line)
        
    for i in range(len(c_line_list)):
        c_x = float(c_line_list[i][0]) # create c coordinates
        c_y = float(c_line_list[i][1])
        c_z = float(c_line_list[i][2])
        
        o_x = float(o_line_list[i][0]) # create o coordinates
        o_y = float(o_line_list[i][1])
        o_z = float(o_line_list[i][2])
        
        co_vector = [o_x - c_x, o_y - c_y, o_z - c_z] # create vector
        co_length = sqrt(co_vector[0]**2 + co_vector[1]**2 + co_vector[2]**2) # calculate length
        
        bond_list.append(co_length)
        
    return bond_list
```